# YOCTO - First build for BBB

Tags: beagleboneblack, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to use for the first time the Yocto tool for my BeagleBoneBlack.
First I run this bash file to install Yocto:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
WKDIR=/work
mkdir -p $WKDIR/beaglebone-black/yocto/sources
mkdir -p $WKDIR/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds
cd $WKDIR/beaglebone-black/yocto/sources
git clone -b morty git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git poky-morty
cd $WKDIR/beaglebone-black/yocto/
source sources/poky-morty/oe-init-build-env builds/build-bbb-morty
```

---

Then I edited the file local.conf at "build-bbb-morty/conf" diretory:

```
MACHINE ?= "beaglebone"
```

and added

```
DL_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/../dl"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-modules kernel-devicetree"
```

---

Then I run bitbake:> `bitbake core-image-minimal`

---

After about 8 hours in my Core i7 five generation I got this result at my terminal output and I have no idea what I need to do to fix it:

---

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
Parsing recipes: 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:02:55
Parsing of 864 .bb files complete (0 cached, 864 parsed). 1318 targets, 67 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-16.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "beaglebone"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.2.1"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp  neon        callconvention-hard        cortexa8"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta              
meta-poky        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "morty:a3fa5ce87619e81d7acfa43340dd18d8f2b2d7dc"

NOTE: Fetching uninative binary shim from http ://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/uninative/1.4/x86_64-nativesdk-libc.tar.bz2;sha256sum=101ff8f2580c193488db9e76f9646fb6ed38b65fb76f403acb0e2178ce7127ca
--2017-01-18 15:51:09--  http ://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/uninative/1.4/x86_64-nativesdk-libc.tar.bz2
Resolving downloads.yoctoproject.org (downloads.yoctoproject.org)... 198.145.20.127
Connecting to downloads.yoctoproject.org (downloads.yoctoproject.org)|198.145.20.127|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2473216 (2.4M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/work/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds/build-bbb-morty/../dl/uninative/101ff8f2580c193488db9e76f9646fb6ed38b65fb76f403acb0e2178ce7127ca/x86_64-nativesdk-libc.tar.bz2’


2017-01-18 15:51:18 (297 KB/s) - ‘/work/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds/build-bbb-morty/../dl/uninative/101ff8f2580c193488db9e76f9646fb6ed38b65fb76f403acb0e2178ce7127ca/x86_64-nativesdk-libc.tar.bz2’ saved [2473216/2473216]

Initialising tasks: 100% |#####################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:14
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
WARNING: attr-native-2.4.47-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL http ://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/attr/attr-2.4.47.src.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
WARNING: libpng-native-1.6.24-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL http ://distfiles.gentoo.org/distfiles/libpng-1.6.24.tar.xz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_image_wic: Function failed: do_image_wic (log file is located at /work/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds/build-bbb-morty/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image_wic.23788)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /work/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds/build-bbb-morty/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image_wic.23788
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function set_image_size
| DEBUG: Python function set_image_size finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_image_wic
| Checking basic build environment...
| Done.
| 
| Build artifacts not found, exiting.<br/>
|   (Please check that the build artifacts for the machine
|    selected in local.conf actually exist and that they
|    are the correct artifacts for the image (.wks file))
| 
| The artifact that couldn't be found was kernel-dir:
|   /work/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds/build-bbb-morty/tmp/deploy/images/beaglebone
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_image_wic (log file is located at /work/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds/build-bbb-morty/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image_wic.23788)
ERROR: Task (/work/beaglebone-black/yocto/sources/poky-morty/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1771 tasks of which 6 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /work/beaglebone-black/yocto/sources/poky-morty/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

While not sure this could be the reason of the problem, the prefered method to add packages to the image, in the local.conf context is using the [CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL) variable.

Therefore change:

> IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-modules kernel-devicetree"

to

> CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "kernel-modules kernel-devicetree"

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with your work method.
It seems to be a build environment problem, but the error log seems to confirm.
your log location at "/work/beaglebone-black/yocto/builds/build-bbb-morty/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image_wic.23788"

Answer (score 0):

Your error log indicates the the URL for fetching binaries failed.

You can try using tunnel through proxy. Or you can run the bitbake again because it can also fail sometimes due to network conditions.